# Variável retornando NaN ou undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Formulário</title>

  <script>

    function salvar() {
      document.getElementById('txtNomeCliente').value = document.getElementById('nomeCompleto').value;

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < document.formVenda.rdEntrega.length; i++) {
        if (document.formVenda.rdEntrega[i].checked)
          break;

      }
      if (parseInt(document.formVenda.rdEntrega[i].value) == 1)
        document.getElementById('txtEntregaSelec').value = "Correios - entrega em até 20 dias (+ R$10,00)";

      else if (parseInt(document.formVenda.rdEntrega[i].value) == 2)
        document.getElementById('txtEntregaSelec').value = "SEDEX - entrega em 7 dias (+ R$25,00)";

      else if (parseInt(document.formVenda.rdEntrega[i].value) == 3)
        document.getElementById('txtEntregaSelec').value = "À retirar (+ R$ 9,00)";




      var indice = document.formVenda.slcFormaPagto.selectedIndex;
      if (document.formVenda.slcFormaPagto.selectedIndex == 0)
        document.getElementById('txtFormaSelec').value = "Transferência em conta corrente";

      else if (document.formVenda.slcFormaPagto.selectedIndex == 1)
        document.getElementById('txtFormaSelec').value = "Cartão de débito";


      else if (document.formVenda.slcFormaPagto.selectedIndex == 2)
        document.getElementById('txtFormaSelec').value = "Cartão de crédito";


      else
        document.getElementById('txtFormaSelec').value = "Boleto bancário";


      if (document.getElementById('ckNews').checked == true) {
        alert("Você aceitou receber a nossa newsletter");
      } else {
        alert('Você não aceitou receber a nosssa newsletter, infelizmente perderá as melhores ofertas');

      }
      document.getElementById("txtValorTotal").value = valorTotal1 + subtot;
    }
    function addProduto() {

      var tabela = document.getElementById('tbProduto');
      var td1 = document.createElement("td");
      var td2 = document.createElement("td");
      var td3 = document.createElement("td");
      var td4 = document.createElement("td");
      var sub = 0 ;
      var tr = document.createElement('tr');
      var cod = parseInt(document.getElementById('codProduto').value);
      var valorTotal = parseInt(0);

      switch (cod) {
        case 1:
          var descricao = "Livro 1";
          var preco = "R$ 35,90";
          var qtde = parseInt(document.getElementById('qntdProd').value);
          var valorTotal = (parseInt(qtde) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 2:
          var descricao = "Livro 2 ";
          var preco = "R$ 11,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 3:
          var descricao = "Livro 3 ";
          var preco = "R$ 5,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 4:
          var descricao = "Livro 4 ";
          var preco = "R$ 85,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 5:
          var descricao = "Livro 5 ";
          var preco = "R$ 65,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 6:
          var descricao = "Livro 6 ";
          var preco = "R$ 25,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 7:
          var descricao = "Livro 7 ";
          var preco = "R$ 61,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          break;
        case 8:
          var descricao = "Livro 8 ";
          var preco = "R$ 26,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 9:
          var descricao = "Livro 9 ";
          var preco = "R$ 47,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal1 += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 10:
          var descricao = "Livro 10 ";
          var preco = "R$ 45,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qtde) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 11:
          var descricao = "Livro 11 ";
          var preco = "R$ 65,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += (parseInt(qntdProd) * preco);
          sub = parseInt(preco*qtde);
          break;
        case 12:
          var descricao = "Livro 12 ";
          var preco = "R$ 95,90";
          var qtde = document.getElementById('qntdProd').value;
          valorTotal += parseInt(qntdProd) * preco;
          sub = parseInt(preco.value*qtde.value);
          break;
        default:
          alert("Código inexistente");
          break;

      }

      var descricaoNode = document.createTextNode(descricao);
      var precoNode = document.createTextNode(preco);
      var qtdeNode = document.createTextNode(qtde);
      var subtot  = document.createTextNode(sub);

      td1.appendChild(descricaoNode);
      td2.appendChild(precoNode);
      td3.appendChild(qtdeNode);
      td4.appendChild(subtot);

      tr.appendChild(td1);
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tr.appendChild(td3);
      tr.appendChild(td4);
     tabela.appendChild(tr);

      document.getElementById('codProduto').value = '';

      document.getElementById('codProduto').focus();
      document.getElementById("txtValorTotal").value = valorTotal;
      salvar();

    }




    function fMasc(objeto, mascara) {
      obj = objeto
      masc = mascara
      setTimeout("fMascEx()", 1)
    }
    function fMascEx() {
      obj.value = masc(obj.value)
    }

    function mCPF(cpf) {
      cpf = cpf.replace(/\D/g, "")
      cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
      cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d)/, "$1.$2")
      cpf = cpf.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{1,2})$/, "$1-$2")
      return cpf
    }

  </script>

</head>

<body>


  <form name="formVenda">
    <label>Nome Completo:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nomeCompleto" maxlength="75" id="nomeCompleto">
    <br>
    <label>CPF:</label>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" maxlength="14" onkeydown="javascript: fMasc( this, mCPF );">
    <br>
    <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="e-mail" name="email" id="email">
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Código Produto</label>
    <input type="number" name="codProduto" id="codProduto">
    <label> Qtde </label>
    <input type="number" name="qntdProd" id='qntdProd'>

    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick='addProduto()'>
    <br>
    <table border="1" name="tbProduto" id="tbProduto">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Nome</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Quantidade</td>
          <td>Subtotal</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <label>Como deseja receber seus produtos:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdEntrega" id="rdEntrega" value="1"> Correios
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdEntrega" id="rdEntrega" value="2" > SEDEX
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rdEntrega" id="rdEntrega" value="3" checked> À retirar
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name='slcFormaPagto' id='slcFormaPagto'>
      <option value='1'>Transferência</option>
      <option value='2'>Débito</option>
      <option value='3'>Crédito</option>
      <option value='4'>Boleto</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type='checkbox' name='ckNews' id='ckNews' value='sim' checked> Eu aceito receber newsletter
    <br>

    <br>
    <br>


  </form>
  <br>


  <label>Cliente:</label>
  <input type="text" name='txtNomeCliente' id='txtNomeCliente' readonly="readonly" value=''>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Entrega selecionada:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtEntregaSelec" id="txtEntregaSelec" readonly="readonly" value=''>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Forma de pagamento selecionada:</label>
  <input type="text" name='txtFormaSelec' id="txtFormaSelec" readonly="readonly" value=''>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Valor total da venda:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtValorTotal" id="txtValorTotal" readonly="readonly" value=''>
  <br>
  <input type='button' value='Finalizar compra' onclick='salvar()'>
</body>

</html>
```

no subtotal da tabela e no total geral da compra, a variavel retorna NaN ou undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`// var preco = "R$ 5,90";
var preco = 5.90;`

Sua variável preço é uma String, é necessário um valor float ou double.